# Using If Statements to then Replace a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, replace

I have a single excel worksheet. I want to replace text in column F IF both Column C has a particular text ("apple") and Column F has a particular number ("56"). I want the replacement value for the Cell in Column F to be "1".

To summarize, if c3=apple and f3=56, I want f3 to be changed to 1.

But if c3 is anything but apple or f3 anything but 56, I do not want anything changed.

The code I have currently is as follows:

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range

For Each x In Range("C2:C9999")

For Each y In Range("F2:F9999")

    If x = "apple" And y = "56" Then y = "1"

Exit For

Next y

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: please include what you have tried.  Also explain what do you want to trigger this change.  Do you want to iterate all the cells and test, do you want to check whenever the data changes?  There are more details needed.  Also realize that this site is about helping overcoming problems in existing code not a show me how to code or code this for me.

Comment: Do you want to do this with VBA?

Comment: Yes I want to do this with VBA by triggering by manually executing a Macro. I added my current code to the post but it does not work....

Comment: Use [edit] to include clarifications in the original post and not comments.

Comment: Also include the errors you are getting and on which line in the [edit]

Comment: No Errors - it runs but it does not make the changes in the excel document. My 56 values are staying as 56.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only need one loop:

```
Sub Macro3()    
    Dim y As Range
    For Each y In Range("F2:F9999")
        If y.offset(,-3) = "apple" And y = 56 Then y = 1
    Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, Mr. Craner! Thank you for your original critique and your help one this!